# Excel 365 Back Calculate Cleaned Data to Raw Data

Tags: excel, iteration, office365, equation, nonlinear-functions

My Problem:

I am using the Microsoft 365 Excel app for desktop.

My dataset comes from a programmed tool that collected raw data and automatically converted it to the final value using an equation I programmed into the tool.

I now realize that I want that raw data, "x", rather than the converted data, and I know that I will need to iteratively back calculate the equation for each converted value in the dataset to get that raw "x" value, but don't know how.

The equation is the following:

> (4.824E-10)*(x^3) - (2.278E-6)*(x^2) + (3.898E-3)*(x) - 2.154

The converted values are each in their own cell in a single column in excel.

What I have tried:

I have tried solving the equation by hand and then plugging in the solved equation to excel, but my understanding is that I would have to do that individually for each data value in the data set.

I also tried the Solver Add-in, but as you can see in the images provided, I am getting an error saying that a formula needs to be provided in the "Set Objective" cell, even though I have provided that, so I am not sure if I am referencing the right sells to make Solver work correctly.

($F$5 contains the answer to the equation that I am trying to back step to find "x", which is cell $AE$5)

First image is a screenshot of how I filled in the Solver window.
[image: First image is a screenshot of how I filled in the Solver window.]

Second image is the error I got when I hit "solve" in the Solver window.
[image: Second image is the error I got when I hit "solve" in the Solver window.]

I would like to make this an automated process for the entire dataset, if possible.

Thank you for any insight that you can provide.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. that said, this looks like a nonlinear, single variable equation, you should use a dedicated solver to find the roots (you may get multiple solutions for `x`), and at least the professional local version of Excel has had an addon for this (just called Solver?) for decades

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply! I have now tried solver, but it is providing an error that I am not sure how to fix, which I will update my original post with.

Comment: Solver can't interpret a simple string and instead you should embed your equation in each cell and reference an adjacent column or columns (effective vector of Xs) such that it either equals the source cell or subtracts it (solve/optimize for `==0` is common) - a more advanced solver can give a resulting collection of the roots and not 1 of N instances of `x` .. this is an approachable topic and can probably work well to at least find one root each given access to Solver (I don't recall, but the basic one wouldn't perform well or at all with a great many constraints as a huge column of inputs)

Comment: As to using Solver. Your objective cell should be a formula. There is no `=` at the beginning. AE5 is empty, should contain starting value. Empty cell means `0`, this is also acceptable. But Solver gives you one result at a time, so you must repeat this manually for each point. To automate the process you can use equations and `Data Table` as in my answer or some iterative method, or macro.

Answer (score 0):

A third-degree equation can be solved in several ways: with the help of the `Solver`, with the help of the `Goal Seek`, by the use of cyclic calculations, and finally there are analytical formulas that can be used and later the calculations can be performed using a `Data Table`.
Here's an example in the screenshot.

[image: equation]